# Is it were or was?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, irregular-forms

In the sentence: "The captain, together with his crew members,_______ struggling to control de ship." Where the blank what supposed to be there "were" or "was"?

Comment: How many people were "struggling"?

Comment: I found that "Together with" makes not plural if the first subject of the sentence is singular. http://www.grammar.com/subjects-joined-by-other-connectors/